# How to create an index on the "name" field of a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to create an index on the name field of a document in mongodb so that when I do a find,I should get all the names to be displayed in the alphabetical order.How can I achieve this ? Can anyone please help me out ...

My documents in mongodb:

```
db.col.find();                                                                                              
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5696256b0c50bf42dcdfeae1"), "name" : "Daniel", "age" : 24 }                                
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569625850c50bf42dcdfeae2"), "name" : "Asha", "age" : 21 }                              
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569625a40c50bf42dcdfeae3"), "name" : "Hampi", "age" : 34 }                              
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5696260f0c50bf42dcdfeae5"), "name" : "Bhavana", "age" : 14 }
```

Comment: Read the documentation [Indexing Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/), especially [Create an Index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need an index in order to display your result alphabetically. What you need is the [`.sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.sort/) method.

```js
db.collection.find().sort({'name': 1})
```

Which returns

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569625850c50bf42dcdfeae2"), "name" : "Asha", "age" : 21 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5696260f0c50bf42dcdfeae5"), "name" : "Bhavana", "age" : 14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5696256b0c50bf42dcdfeae1"), "name" : "Daniel", "age" : 24 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569625a40c50bf42dcdfeae3"), "name" : "Hampi", "age" : 34 }
```

Creating an index on a field in your document will not automatically sort your result on that particular field you still need to use the `.sort()` method. see [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)

---

If you want to return an array of all names in your documents in ascending order then you will need to use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) stage where you sort your documents by "name" in ascending order. The last stage is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you group your documents and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator to return an array of "names"

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$sort": { "name": 1 } },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "names": { "$push": "$name" } } }
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "names" : [ "Asha", "Bhavana", "Daniel", "Hampi" ] }
```

Comment: But I think the reason to add index not just because user wants to use `sort` as it is, but he also want to execute sort queries fast. When you have proper index setup by field `name` and you need a sorted result back then there is no need for any extra manipulations and query will executed fast. In your case.